# How to expand and collapse a div based on div id in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have few links and div coming from ng repeat.When I click on any link it will goes/scroll to same div of same id.That is working fine.but here I need to expand the div based on id.When I click on any link only those div should expand others remains collapse..so on.I tried with based on id but it is not working,Can anyone help me with the code below and updated demo on plunker 
https://plnkr.co/edit/MRZgVHYMWsff022Mq3dV?p=preview

### HTML

```
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'></script>
<script  src="script.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css'>
 <body ng-app="app">     
  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
   <div class="my-fixed-header">
      <a href="index.html#/#anchor{{x}}"  ng-click="gotoDiv(x)" ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3,4,5]">
        Go to Div {{x}}
      </a>
   </div>
    <div class="scroll-div">

      <div style="border:1px solid;" id="anchor{{group.id}}"  ng-repeat="group in groups">
        <div class="parents"  ng-click="open(group)"><i ng-class="{'glyphicon-minus': group.isOpen, 'glyphicon-plus': !group.isOpen}"></i> {{ group.title }}        
        </div>
        {{ group.content }}
        <ul class="childs" ng-show="group.isOpen">
          <li ng-repeat="item in group.list">
            <span ng-bind-html="item"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

### css

```
<style type="text/css">
    .scroll-div {
      height: 200px;
      overflow: scroll;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .anchor {
      border: 2px dashed red;
      padding: 10px 10px 200px 10px;
    }
    .my-fixed-header {

    }
    .my-fixed-header > a {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 5px 15px;
    }
  </style>
```

### script.js

```
var app=angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize','angular.filter']);
app.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope,$location,$anchorScroll) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;

  $scope.open = function (item) {
    $scope.groups.filter(a=> a ===item).forEach(a=>{
      a.isOpen = !a.isOpen;
    });
    $scope.closeOthers(item);

  }

  $scope.closeOthers = function (item) {
    $scope.groups.filter(a=> a !==item).forEach(a=>{
      a.isOpen = false;
    });
  }
$scope.gotoDiv = function(x) {


      if(x){
          $scope.groups.forEach(a=>{
            a.isOpen = true;
          });

      }
      else{
          a.isOpen = false; 

      }
     };

  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      id:'1',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',
      id:'2',
      list: ['item1b',
        '<b>item2b </b> blah ',
        'item3b'] 
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',
      id:'3',
      list: ['item1c',
        '<b>item2c </b> blah ',
        'sss3c'] 

    },
    {
      title: 'title 4',
      id:'4',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',
      id:'5',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    }
  ];
$scope.groups[0].isOpen = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, you can add 1 more condition (`if (a.id === x.toString())`) to check the selected div in your gotoDiv function as follows:

```
$scope.gotoDiv = function (x) {
  if (x) {
    $scope.groups.forEach(a = > {
      if (a.id === x.toString()) {
        a.isOpen = true;
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    a.isOpen = false;
  }
};
```